# AMPHTML Email - AMP forms are blocked on Android And not working on IOS

Tags: gmail, amp-html

I'm working on AMPHTML Email and I have 2 main issues on them: 
 1. I can't debug the code or preview it. I validated the code on

https://validator.ampproject.org/#htmlFormat=AMP4EMAIL
But the result in the AMP playground or as AMP pages is totally different from the final email I'm getting on my email!

1. All the AMP images are not working
2. AMP Forms can load it on iphone, but it's blocked the gmail app on android  due to "Javascript Forms are disabled"

Here is the code that I'm testing on Mobile:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email>
<head>
<meta  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>


<style amp-custom>
    body{
        margin: 10px 50px 50px 10px; 
      }

#container{
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px; 
  } 

      .bold-txt{
        font-weight: bold;
      }
        .center{
    text-align:center;
  }

.max-width{
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
}

      #amp-form-name, #amp-form-mail {
        display: block;
        width: 85%;
        margin: 10px auto;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    }

    #amp-form-date, #amp_webinar_time {
        width: 92%;
        margin: 10px auto;
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    }

    #amp-form-date, #amp_webinar_time {
        width: 92%;
        margin: 10px auto;
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    }

    #amp-form-cta, .ampstart-btn .caps {
        background-color: #009be8;
        color: #f2f1f1;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 14px;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 2% 5% 10% 5%;
        height: 65px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body class="container-margin">
    <div id="container">

      <p> Hi Mustafa, </p>

      WildFit has been a tremendous success, with over 10, 000 students since Eric Edmeades and I decided to team up to bring this to the wider world.

<p class="bold-txt">We’ve seen this change lives…change families… change marriages…</p>


<h2>Your Tribe Is Waiting For You</h2>


      <p> Lorem Ipsum has been the <span class="bold-txt"> industry's standard ever since the 1500s,</span> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled. 
</p>    

      <amp-carousel width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides" autoplay delay="2100">
          <amp-img src="https://static.mindvalley.com/public/assets/2018/10/clUh_marleen-crabbe.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://static.mindvalley.com/public/assets/2018/10/4Gxo_chang.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="another sample image">      
    </amp-img>
    <amp-img src="https://static.mindvalley.com/public/assets/2018/10/erVA_debora-trimpe.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="and another sample image"></amp-img>


</amp-carousel>



        <h2 class="center"> Register Now </h2>

<div class="entry-headline h5 txt-white">Discover 5 Mind Hacks For Extreme Resilience in this FREE Masterclass</div>



    <div class="amp-wrapper max-width">
    <p class="amp-form-shortcode"> </p>
    <form method="post" action-xhr="https://blog.mindvalley.com/services/blink-forms/blink-endpoint.php">
        <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3"> <input type="text" class="block border-none p0 m0" name="uname" placeholder="Name..." id="amp-form-name" required=""><input type="email" class="block border-none p0 m0" name="email" placeholder="Email..." id="amp-form-mail" required="">
            <select name="amp-form-date" id="amp-form-date" required="">
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden="">Select a day</option>
                <option value="instant-replay"> Watch Now Instantly</option>
                <option value="watch-later"> Watch Later Today</option>
                <option value="2019-02-14"> Thu, 2019-02-14</option>
                <option value="2019-02-15"> Fri, 2019-02-15</option>
                <option value="2019-02-16"> Sat, 2019-02-16</option>
                </select>
                <p> </p>

      <input type="submit" value="RESERVE MY SPOT NOW"           class="ampstart-btn caps" id="amp-form-cta">
                  <div submit-success=""> <template type="amp-          mustache"> Thanks {{name}} For Enrolling In. You Will Be Redirected...           
     </template>
     </div>
        <div submit-error=""> <template type="amp-mustache"> Error!          
        Thanks {{name}} for trying joining our webinar. Please make 
        sure your mail is correct. </template>
     </div>
      </form>
         </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

It's working fine on the browser as AMP HTML but it's not working at all if I send it on the email!

This is how it looks like on the real devices ( Android / IOS ):

[image: this is how it looks like on android / gmail APP]

[image: this is how it looks in IOS]

And it's not working on both!!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you positive that you're enabled for testing AMP4Email? Did you sign up for developer preview and approved? Note that forms in AMP are unique among AMP HTML components in that they don't have a markup tag unique to AMP. e.g. amp-list, amp-img. Forms might be displaying and giving you the false impression that it's working because it is being parsed as the native  tag.